# Display a string returned by contract in python

Tags: web3.py

I have written a simple contract to set a string and then return it back. Can I display the string returned from contract function ?

```
import web3
import json

from web3 import Web3

def main():
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
    w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]
    print(w3.eth.defaultAccount)
    with open('abi', 'r') as abi_definition:
        abi = json.load(abi_definition)
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress('0x82A978B3f5962A5b0957d9ee9eEf472EE55B42F1'),abi=abi,bytecode='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')
    tc = contract.constructor().transact()

    contract.functions.storeID('yes').transact()
    get = contract.functions.getID().call()
    print(get)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is the output:

```
    0x82A978B3f5962A5b0957d9ee9eEf472EE55B42F1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1214, in call_contract_function
    output_data = decode_abi(output_types, return_data)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/abi.py", line 63, in decode_abi
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 22, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 135, in decode
    yield HeadTailDecoder.as_decoder(tail_decoder=decoder)(stream)
  File "/home/sapan/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 113, in decode
    start_pos = decode_uint_256(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 162, in decode
    raw_data = cls.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 244, in read_data_from_stream
    len(data),
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/Node.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/Node.py", line 15, in main
    get = contract.functions.getID().call()
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 979, in call
    **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/~/PycharmProjects/GlobalCA/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1236, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

I am trying to find a way to display the string retuned by 'getID'

Comment: Yes. Now do you have a follow-up question?

Comment: How exactly can I do that ?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: `buildTransaction` doesn't actually do anything with the blockchain. You want `sendTransaction`. And for your `view` function (`getID` is, I assume, a `view` function), you want `call`.

Comment: Ok. I replaced the above two build transact calls with

contract.functions.storeID('yes').transact()
    get = contract.functions.getID().call()


And now I am getting 

web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the current code and the full error.

Comment: My guess would be that the contract is not actually deployed at that address? Can you share details of how you're deploying the contract?

Comment: So I wrote the contract on remix id, and copied the abi and bytecode to my python code. Ran the testrpc-py and then executed the python code. I am assuming that 'tc = contract.constructor().transact()' is deploying my contract

Comment: Nothing in your current code has the source code or bytecode for your contract, so it can't possibly be deploying it.

Comment: This line 
`contract = w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress('0x82A978B3f5962A5b0957d9ee9eEf472EE55B42F1'),abi=abi,bytecode='')`

Comment: Couldnt fit bytecode in the comment so removed it

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but please edit your question to have the actual code you're running in it.

Comment: In any case, you'll have to deploy the contract and get the address from that. Then use that address to make your transaction and call.

Comment: This is the whole code. The line mentioned in my comment is actually 6th line of the main function.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason Stack Overflow didn't show me that edit. I see it in the current version of the question.

Comment: FIgured it out. I wasnt adding the contract address in the call() arguments. Thanks, this conversation helped a lot.